# How do I program a simulation of concentric circles on water? and should I use matplotlib or pygame?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pygame, geometry

I need to program a simulation as homework, but I can't figure how.
I need a simulation of a percussion on water that causes concentric circles, I need to set the location of the circles, the frequency and the radius of the circles

I' ve tried several ways but not even one of them seems to work decently. I' have tried doing it with pygame but it seems to lag a lot and doesn't work correctly. Then I've tried by doing it with matplotlib, but since I am not so experienced with it I don't know how to exactly do it

```
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600])
black = (0,0,0)
keep_going = True

white = (255,255,255)
freq = 10
num_circle = 0
radius = 0
while keep_going:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            keep_going = False

        for x in range(100):
            radius = radius + 1
            num_circle = math.ceil(radius / freq)
            screen.fill(white)

            radiusMax = num_circle * freq

            pace = freq / radiusMax


            for y in range(num_circle, 1, -1):

                radiusY = int(((pace * (num_circle - y)) + pace) * radiusMax)+radius

                pygame.draw.circle(screen, black,(400, 300), radiusY, 1)

        pygame.display.update()           
pygame.quit()
```

this is what I am trying with pygame, just a not finished idea, but it still doesn't work so good.

https://www.edumedia-sciences.com/de/media/645-kreiswellen-wasserwellen

this is exactly what I am looking for.
Should I do it with pygame or matplotlib or something else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found a solution.

```
import pygame
import math
import time
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800,600])
black = (0,0,0)
keep_going = True

white = (255,255,255)
freq = 10
num_cerchi = 0
raggio = 0



while keep_going:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            keep_going = False


    raggio = raggio + 1
    num_cerchi = math.ceil(raggio / freq)
    screen.fill(white)

    raggioMax = num_cerchi * freq

    passo = freq / raggioMax


    for y in range(num_cerchi, 1, -1):
        # 1, -1

        raggioY = int(((passo * (num_cerchi - y)) + passo) * raggioMax) + (raggio % freq)

        pygame.draw.circle(screen, black,(400, 300), raggioY, 1)

    pygame.display.update()           
pygame.quit()
```

I'm not very sure if the frequency concept is right, but it works